# Print all numbers in range show only the primes

Tags: java

I have been working on this for two days with absolutely no luck. I need my program to print a range given by the user and show all the prime numbers in the range. All non-prime numbers should be printed out as "-". I need to have 10 numbers per line, followed by a | along with the last number in the line. It would look something like this:

71 - 73 - - - - - 79 - | 80

I know I need to use printf, but I can't figure out where to put my print statement or how to stop a printf statement from stopping at 10 numbers before starting a new line. Also I can't figure out how to make the non-prime numbers print as "-" while still using printf. Everytime I try it I get an error. Here is the code after the user inputs his numbers:

```
for(d=start;d<end;d++) { 
        b=0; 
        for(c=1;c<=d;c++){ 
            if(d%c==0) 
                b=b+1;
        } 
        if(b==2){ 
            System.out.printf("%4d", d); 
            //prints prime numbers with the spacing required
            primes=primes+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and this outputs what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out shortly after I asked the question, here is the code I used:

```
for(d=start;d<=end;d++) { 
        b=0; 
        for(c=1;c<=d;c++){ 
            if(d%c==0) 
                b=b+1;
        } 
        if(b==2){ 
            primes=primes+1;
            if(d!=start){
                System.out.printf("%4d", d);
            }
        }else{
            if(d!=start){
                System.out.printf("   -");
            }
        }
        if(d%10==0&&d!=start){
            System.out.printf(" | ");
            System.out.printf("%4d", d);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make a counter, and when counter%10==0 then you print a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break down the problem into smaller subproblems. For example, print out a list of primer numbers and don't worry about format or print out the numbers in a given range with 10 numbers per row. After you figure out how to do each of these separately, *then* try to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in python to give you a startup point, consider the code below,

```
def prime_display(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if is_prime(i) == True:
            print(i, end=' ')
        else:
            if divisible_by_10(i):
                print(f'- | {i}', end='\n')

            print('-', end=' ')

def divisible_by_10(n):
    if (n % 10) == 0:
        return True
    return False

def is_prime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if (n % i) == 0:
                return False
        else:
                return True
    else:
        return False

prime_display(39)
```

Answer (score -1):

Compile: gcc prime.c
Run (for the range 1-200): ./a.out 1 200

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int isPrime(int n){
    if(n==1) return 0;
    int i=2;
    while(i<=sqrt(n))
        if(n%i++==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a,b,count;
    if(argc<3)
        return 0;
    a=atoi(argv[1]);
    b=atoi(argv[2]);
    count=1;
    for(;a<=b;a++){
        if(isPrime(a)) printf("%d ",a);
        else printf("- ");
        if(count++==10){
            printf("| %d\n",a);
            count=1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```